# Filter ObservableCollection based on date Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, filter, observablecollection

First time posting so sorry for the formatting if it is incorrect.

I am having trouble filtering an observable collection based upon a date given. The application will have a calendar where the user can click a date and below will appear the appointments for that date.

There are two classes, one being the dataManager which will get the data from Azure, and the appointment page itself.

Here is the appointmentPage Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using XamForms.Controls;

namespace TodoAzure
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AppointmentPage : ContentPage
    {
        TodoItemManager manager;
        CalendarVM vm = new CalendarVM();
        public AppointmentPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            manager = TodoItemManager.DefaultManager;
            calendar.DateClicked += (sender, e) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(calendar.SelectedDates);
            };
            calendar.SetBinding(Calendar.DateCommandProperty, nameof(vm.DateChosen));
            calendar.SetBinding(Calendar.SelectedDateProperty, nameof(vm.DateSelected));
            calendar.BindingContext = vm;
        }
        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            // Set syncItems to true in order to synchronize the data on startup when running in offline mode
            await RefreshItems(true, syncItems: false);
        }
        //PULL TO REFRESH
        public async void OnRefresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var list = (ListView)sender;
            Exception error = null;
            try
            {
                await RefreshItems(false, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                error = ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                list.EndRefresh();
            }
            if (error != null)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Refresh Error", "Couldn't refresh data (" + error.Message + ")", "OK");
            }
        }
        public async void OnSyncItems(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await RefreshItems(true, true);
        }
        private async Task RefreshItems(bool showActivityIndicator, bool syncItems)
        {
            using (var scope = new ActivityIndicatorScope(syncIndicator, showActivityIndicator))
        {
            appointmentPage.ItemsSource = await manager.GetAppointmentItemsAsync(syncItems);      
        }
    }
    private class ActivityIndicatorScope : IDisposable
    {
        private bool showIndicator;
        private ActivityIndicator indicator;
        private Task indicatorDelay;
        public ActivityIndicatorScope(ActivityIndicator indicator, bool showIndicator)
        {
            this.indicator = indicator;
            this.showIndicator = showIndicator;
            if (showIndicator)
            {
                indicatorDelay = Task.Delay(2000);
                SetIndicatorActivity(true);
            }
            else
            {
                indicatorDelay = Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
        private void SetIndicatorActivity(bool isActive)
        {
            this.indicator.IsVisible = isActive;
            this.indicator.IsRunning = isActive;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (showIndicator)
            {
                indicatorDelay.ContinueWith(t => SetIndicatorActivity(false), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the data manger class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync; 
#if OFFLINE_SYNC_ENABLED
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync;
#endif

namespace TodoAzure
{
    public partial class TodoItemManager
    {
        static TodoItemManager defaultInstance = new TodoItemManager ();
        MobileServiceClient client;
        IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> todoTable;
        IMobileServiceTable<AppointmentItem> appointmentTable;
        private TodoItemManager ()
        {
            this.client = new MobileServiceClient (
                Constants.ApplicationURL);
            this.todoTable = client.GetTable<TodoItem> ();
            this.appointmentTable = client.GetTable<AppointmentItem>();  
        } 
        public static TodoItemManager DefaultManager 
        {
            get { return defaultInstance; }
            private set { defaultInstance = value; }
        }   
        public MobileServiceClient CurrentClient 
        {
            get { return client; }
        }  
        public bool IsOfflineEnabled 
        {
            get { return appointmentTable is Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.IMobileServiceSyncTable<AppointmentItem>;        }
    }   
    // INSERT AND UPDATE METHODS
    public async Task SaveTaskAsync (TodoItem item)
    {
        if (item.Id == null) 
            await todoTable.InsertAsync (item);
        else 
            await todoTable.UpdateAsync (item);
    }
    public async Task SaveTaskAsync(AppointmentItem appointment)
    {
        if (appointment.Id == null)
            await appointmentTable.InsertAsync(appointment);
        else
            await appointmentTable.UpdateAsync(appointment);
    }
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<AppointmentItem>> GetAppointmentItemsAsync(bool syncItems = false)
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<AppointmentItem> items = await appointmentTable
                    .ToEnumerableAsync();
            return new ObservableCollection<AppointmentItem>(items);
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"Invalid sync operation: {0}", msioe.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"Sync error: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "having trouble" - could you be more specific?  Are you getting errors or exceptions?  Is it behaving oddly, or crashing?  I don't see any logic in your code that even attempts to date filter?

Comment: I am unsure how to filter the ObservableCollection with the date given in `vm.SelectedDates` in the Appointment Page. I have tried a couple of methods given in other Stack Overflow Questions but have not succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

to filter an IEnumerable by Date, try this

```
// items is ObservableCollection<AppointmentItem>
var filtered = items.Where(x => x.Date == SelectedDate);
```

Comment: It did not work ): Will the Filtering have to take place in the AppointmentPage class as this is where the user defines the SelectedDate?

Comment: see my edit - I had the class name instead of instance name in my example.  If it still doesn't work, please be more specific - did you verify in the debugger that a filtered list of data is being returned?  As far as where you put the filter expression, that's up to you.

Comment: I am now seeing this error "
Error CS1061 'Task<ObservableCollection<AppointmentItem>>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ObservableCollection<AppointmentItem>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". Slowly but surely getting there.

Comment: you need to include "System.LINQ;" in your using statements